# React Native - Build Offline Bundle on Debug Build

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Right now, I am used to using Debug Mode and React Native will open the app and the packager will package it on the spot. This is good for development.

And then I can switch to Release Mode (in Xcode) via my Scheme. The bundle will be prebundled. This is good because as soon as the app opens, the JS is loaded and there is no need to wait.

My problem is that I have a Xcode dependency that only works on Debug mode, but I need certain Bash script to run as soon as the app loads. But if I have to wait for the packager to bundle, my script timing is off.

So does anyone know a way to build main.jsbundle ahead of time, and still be in debug mode (Xcode scheme)?